# Ionic Camera generated string URL size too big to store (as a string) in Firebase

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-native

i am using ionic camera plugin https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera to capture image and and store into Firebase, but when i am uploading an image file of size greater than 2 mb , while storing in Firebase it is giving error that string longer than 1048487 bytes.
Any suggestion how can i shorten string URL size or any other way of storing any picture of ant size.

My Code :

```
takePicture()
 {

   const options: CameraOptions = {
   quality: 30,
   destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
   encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
   mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
   allowEdit: true,
   sourceType: 1,
   saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
};
   this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
   this.cardopen = !this.cardopen;
   this.takephoto = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
console.log(this.takephoto);
}, (err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
}
```

Opera DOM:

```
core.js:4197 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: The value of 
 property "ImageUrl" is longer than 1048487 bytes.
FirebaseError: The value of property "ImageUrl" is longer than 1048487 bytes.
```

[String Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDHDb.png)

Comment: Are you converting your base64 image into a blob?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should upload the image to the firebase storage first. After that you save the download url in your firestore document to show the image.
[Upload to firebase storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files?hl=en#upload_from_a_string)

With firebase storage you have no limits on data size. Draw back is that the image loads slow, but you can create a firebase function that do some image processing to generate a thumbnail.

Even for this firebase created an [extension](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/storage-resize-images?hl=en) to resize the image.